# Jacobi method to solve linear systems in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration, linear-algebra

How would you code this in MATLAB? [image]

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work quite right.

```
function x = my_jacobi(A,b, tot_it)
%Inputs:
%A: Matrix
%b: Vector
%tot_it: Number of iterations
%Output:
%:x The solution after tot_it iterations
    n = length(A);
    x = zeros(n,1);
    for k = 1:tot_it
      for j = 1:n
        for i = 1:n
            if (j ~= i) 
                x(i) = -((A(i,j)/A(i,i)) * x(j) + (b(i)/A(i,i)));

            else
                continue;
            end
          end
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`j` is an iterator of a sum over each `i`, so you need to change their order. Also the formula has a sum and in your code you're not adding anything so that's another thing to consider. The last thing I see that you're omitting is that you should save the previous state of `x`because the right side of the formula needs it. You should try something like this:

```
function x = my_jacobi(A,b, tot_it)
  %Inputs:
  %A: Matrix
  %b: Vector
  %tot_it: Number of iterations
  %Output:
  %:x The solution after tot_it iterations
  n = length(A);
  x = zeros(n,1);
  s = 0; %Auxiliar var to store the sum.
  xold = x
  for k = 1:tot_it
    for i = 1:n
      for j = 1:n
        if (j ~= i) 
          s = s + (A(i,j)/A(i,i)) * xold(j);
        else
          continue;
        end
      end
      x(i) = -s + b(i)/A(i,i);
      s = 0;
    end
    xold = x;
  end
end
```